# MySQL Query issue.show latest date for unique entries

Tags: mysql

here is a simplified version of my database

```
ID#
Date (Datetime)
Customer (Varchar)
Item (Varchar)
```

Each customer can have multiple items and every row will have a unique datetime stamp.

I am trying to write a query to show the latest entry for each item attached belonging to each Customer

If that doesn't make sense this might be better:

For instance data.

```
1   1/1/12 00:00:00   Cust1  Item1 
2   2/1/12 00:00:00   Cust1  Item1 
3   3/1/12 00:00:00   Cust1  Item2 
4   2/1/12 00:00:00   Cust2  Item1 
5   3/1/12 00:00:00   Cust2  Item1 
6   4/1/12 00:00:00   Cust2  Item1
```

Should display

```
2   2/1/12 00:00:00   Cust1  Item1 
3   3/1/12 00:00:00   Cust1  Item2 
6   4/1/12 00:00:00   Cust2  Item1
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM   tbl a
JOIN   (
       SELECT MAX(ID) AS ID FROM tbl GROUP BY Customer, Item
       ) b ON a.ID = b.ID
```

This gets the highest `ID` per customer (assuming it's an auto-incremented value and the highest value is also the latest), and since it's unique, we simply join the same table on the `ID` column, which will only return the latest row per customer.

Comment: The ID is just an auto increment value.

Comment: This query doesn't display all the data, it only shows the latest entry for each customer. It should show the latest entry for each item belonging to each customer.

Comment: @user1568527, oops my bad. That's a simple fix (adding `Item` to the `GROUP BY`). Check the updated solution.

Comment: Yea, that seems to be it. Thank you